# Tar files only in last directory listed in a path

Tags: tar

I'm trying to write a bash script that tars all files within a specific directory.

I have this command written in the script:

```
tar -cvf /opt/file/myFiles.tar.gz /opt/data/name/logs/
```

So basically I want a tar file called myFiles.tar.gz to be created in /opt/file and when I untar the file, it should give me the folder logs and everything inside logs.

Instead, I get the folder opt and I have to go through data and name as well before reaching the logs folder.

Is there a way so that when I untar the file, I only get what's in the logs folder and I wouldn't have to go through opt/data/name? I also tried doing `/opt/data/name/logs/*` but it gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU and BSD `tar` have a `-C` option for that:

```bash
tar -cv -f /opt/file/myFiles.tar.gz -C /opt/data/name/ logs/
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one?

```
tar -cvf /opt/file/myFiles.tar.gz -C /opt/data/name/logs/ .
```